# Error when trying to test interrupts with raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

```
# Test interrupts.
import os
import select

write_once(os.path.join('/sys/class/gpio', 'export'), '22')

# Pin to work with
pin_base = '/sys/class/gpio/gpio22/'


def write_once(path, value):
   with open(path, 'w') as f:
      f.write(value)


f = open(os.path.join(pin_base, 'value'), 'r')

write_once(os.path.join(pin_base, 'direction'),
       'in')
write_once(os.path.join(pin_base, 'edge'),
       'falling')

po = select.poll()
po.register(f, select.POLLPRI)

while 1:
   events = po.poll(100)
   if not events:
      print ('timeout')
   else:
        f.seek(0)
        state_last = f.read()
        print 'Val: %s' % state_last
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/pi/trigger.py", line 5, in <module>
> write_once(os.path.join('/sys/class/gpio', 'export'), '22')
> NameError: name 'write_once' is not defined
> ```

i'm trying to export gpio 22 using write_once and having error.. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Move:

```
def write_once(path, value):
   with open(path, 'w') as f:
      f.write(value)
```

up toward the top of the file, before the first call to it.

Statements are executed in order, one at a time, so you're calling it before it's defined. Alternatively, put the calls your making to `write_once()` inside a different function, and make sure you call that function after defining `write_once()`.

Here's the first suggestion:

```
# Test interrupts.
import os
import select


def write_once(path, value):
   with open(path, 'w') as f:
      f.write(value)

write_once(os.path.join('/sys/class/gpio', 'export'), '22')

# Pin to work with
pin_base = '/sys/class/gpio/gpio22/'

f = open(os.path.join(pin_base, 'value'), 'r')

write_once(os.path.join(pin_base, 'direction'), 'in')
write_once(os.path.join(pin_base, 'edge'), 'falling')

po = select.poll()
po.register(f, select.POLLPRI)

while True:
   events = po.poll(100)
   if not events:
      print ('timeout')
   else:
        f.seek(0)
        state_last = f.read()
        print 'Val: %s' % state_last
```

And here's the second:

```
# Test interrupts.
import os
import select


def run():
    write_once(os.path.join('/sys/class/gpio', 'export'), '22')

    # Pin to work with
    pin_base = '/sys/class/gpio/gpio22/'

    f = open(os.path.join(pin_base, 'value'), 'r')

    write_once(os.path.join(pin_base, 'direction'), 'in')
    write_once(os.path.join(pin_base, 'edge'), 'falling')

    po = select.poll()
    po.register(f, select.POLLPRI)

    while True:
       events = po.poll(100)
       if not events:
          print ('timeout')
       else:
            f.seek(0)
            state_last = f.read()
            print 'Val: %s' % state_last

def write_once(path, value):
   with open(path, 'w') as f:
      f.write(value)

run()
```

Note that with the second example, it doesn't matter what order you define the two functions in, as long as they're both defined before you call `run()`.